# how to implement SOA in java?

Tags: java, soa

I am new for SOA.i want to known how to implement SOA in Java.i am go through various sites that only deals with the concept,it don't give clear idea about the implementation details,for using SOA in Java.plz provide an details for how to implements SOA.

Thanks

Comment: The reason for the lack of a clear idea about implementation details is due to the very general/wide/buzzwordy nature of the term. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english

Comment: A proper implementation of SOA requires Powerpoint, Salesmanship, Vaporware and a subscription to Gartner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOA is about design principles (some might even say it's a paradigm) and less about tools and implementation, so it is difficult to fire up your IDE and "implement an SOA".

Because SOA is bigger and complexer than, say, a design pattern, most sources on the subject only deal with the theory and do not discuss implementation details.

If you understand the concept and know Java, then you can start implementing on top of existing frameworks (see other answers), by reusing existing components, or, if you are feeling I-want-to-write-a-C-compiler-from-scratch-y, you can try to design and code your very own SOA from the ground up.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Axis 2 web site on Apache:-

[axis2](http://projects.apache.org/projects/axis2.html)

This is a mature well thought out SOAP framework which is widly deployed.

As well as the soap client and server componemtns there are a number of development tools
with will enable you to SOAPify an existing java class, or, generate the Java class stubs from a SOAP WSDL definition.

Comment: @adranale actually this is very good answer, because it suites to small example which is probably asked here. This way it is possible to take same simple functionalities and expose it as axis web services and play with them. Very good start of service oriented architecture.

Comment: @adranale -- the question was "how to implement"!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/home.html):

> Apache ServiceMix is an open source
>   ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) that
>   combines the functionality of a
>   Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)
>   and an Event Driven Architecture (EDA)
>   to create an agile, enterprise ESB.

Additionally, the latest major release of ServiceMiix is built on top of [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgi) - a "module system and service platform for Java".

Answer (score 0):

SOA is a thinking, it’s an architectural concept, and web service is one of the technical approaches to complete it. Web services are the preferred standards to achieve SOA.

If you need to integrate or make an existing system as a business service, you just need to create loosely coupled wrappers which is your own wrapper and will wrap your custom systems and expose the systems functionality in a generic fashion to the external world.

In SOA we need services to be loosely coupled. A web service communicates using the SOAP protocol which is XML based, which is very loosely coupled. It answers the what part of the service.

you can use [Axis2](http://projects.apache.org/projects/axis2.html) web services to implement it.