# CAP theorem or Brewer's therom in plain english?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, cap-theorem

I have read the wiki, and I understand sentences explaining the  Consistency Availability and Partition tolerance but grasping  CAP/Brewer's theorem  is like holding a fish.

I believe there exist a better intuitive way  explaining and understanding CAP theorem.

Any good text ?

{
Before someone think question formed as Plain-English-Explanation are nonconstructive, here is a list of all other great Plain-English-Explanations question.

[What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

[Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english)

[What is SOA "in plain english"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english)

[Can you explain what "git reset" does in plain english?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english)

}

Comment: [Please stop calling databases CP or AP](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html) contains an explanation

Answer (score 3):

CAP theorem says that in case of Network Partition(P) in a distributed data store, one needs to sacrifice either Consistency(C) or Availability(A).

The *two out of three* terminology (CA/CP/AP) often used is confusing as it seems that each of C, A and P are some characteristics of a system but P actually is a *situation* which forces to pick only one of the *characteristics* out of C and A.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding

CAP theorem is acronym for:

- Consistency: see the most recent data without a delay
- availability:  system should give a response to every request
- partitioning: means distributing your data in different location.

CAP theorem says you can not achieve 3 of them.  you should stick with two and sacrifice one!

Lets see why!

1- If you need consistency and availability. You should forget partitioning because as you partition there is a slight window of opportunity that nodes lag behind the recent data.

2- If  availability and partitioning is the goal you have to pay the cost of consistency as explained in 1.

3-  finally if you choose  partitioning and consistency you should sacrifice availability to handle lags of deferent nodes to have recent data.

see the picture below for different database vendors in this theorem.
[image]

picture from http://www.abramsimon.com

Comment: Brewer made it explicit that it is misconception that you can do with two and not have third. You can't have a distributed (multinode) DB that is truly partition tolerant.

Comment: You are wrong it explicitly states that it is impossible for a distributed computer system to simultaneously provide all three of them!

Comment: follow the link and listen Cap definition from Brewer himself   http://www.se-radio.net/2015/05/the-cap-theorem-then-and-now/

Comment: Let me restate better.  Brewer talks about the trade offs and not about a binary world where one has to choose from AP vs CP.

Comment: RDBMS are not available in case cluster nodes have a network partition between them. There is no such class of systems as CA. RDBMS choose Consistency and therefore in case of network partition are not available. The "choose 2 of three" view of CAP theorem is wrong, as explained above.