# How to remove SOA Application from SOA Server on Weblogic 11g

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, weblogic11g, soa-suite

I have a Domain in Weblogic 10.3.6 with SOA Server included. I just deployed a SOA Application called `soa_1` with BPEL Process called `HelloWorld` using JDeveloper. This is the structure shown in JDeveloper:

```
Application Servers
      Weblogic Server
             SOA
               AdminServer
                    default
                        soa_1[1.0]
                             helloworld_client_ep (ws)
```

I just want to undeploy/remove this `soa_1` application! I didn't find any information on the internet about how to remove a SOA Application. When I right-click the `soa_1` element of the tree it seems to have a `Delete` option but it is not available

Comment: [What is SOA in plain english?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2026523/2173738)

Comment: The undeploy instructions here don't work? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e10226/soacompapp_deploy.htm#SOAAG3803

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing Oh! I never payed attention because i never found that wizard they talk about. But now that i read again i see there is an "Enterprise Manager" that i can use to undeploy my application. Even if it doesn't seem to be the tool they are talking about that enterprise manager helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the link posted in the comments above by "Display Name is missing" Oracle provides us with `Fusion Middleware Control - Enterprise Manager` that we can use to deploy/undeploy soa applications and lot of things. The problem is i couldn't access that Enterprise Manager at ip:port/em because i didn't install it when i created the domain so i used the configuration wizard to extend my domain. Once i added "Enterprise Manager" to my domain i could access ip:port/em and undeploy my SOA Application

Comment: Glad that link helped. If you want to - you can accept your own answer so other users know

Answer (score 1):

login em console and expand **soa** and select your composite right click and select **SOA Deploymen**t and select **undeploy** as shown below.[image] and after click **undeploy** after you will get conformation message and check you composite is removed under soa partitions.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't click on (ws) - that's the end point. Click on the SOA composite name just above it: soa_1 - then **undeploy** shows up in the menu.